# Does a surface in front of a radiator (not in contact) have a significant effect on the room's temperature or heating rate?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity

Does a surface in front of a radiator (not in contact) have a significant effect on the room's temperature or heating rate?

Some time ago I had a discussion about it, and despite none of us knowing anything about thermodynamics, we were pretty sure of our opposite intuitions (just like in politics, hehe).

I guess a quick way to determine it was to do the experiment in question, but since it may be quite straight forward for somebody who knows about the topic, and to avoid turning on the radiator in the middle of the summer, maybe it's better to just ask the experts here :-)

Just in case the answer depends very much on the setting, this particular set-up is a radiator of 0.9m x 0.5m at about 50ºC, just like [one of these](http://www.theradiatorfactory.com/catalogue/ex/Twine_Pinch_LR.pdf), on a room of 10m x 5m x 2.5m at an initial temperature of about 16ºC. The objects in front of the radiator (right next to it but not in contact) would be:

- *a chair* (made of thin synthetic leather (PVC) and aluminum), similar to [this one](http://www.theofficeleader.com/images/thumbs/0009576_200.jpeg)

or

- *a wooden 0.5m x 1.5m x 0.05m framed mirror* (like [this one](http://shard3.1stdibs.us.com/archivesE/1stdibs/062112/huniford_jb//11/B.jpg), but on an aluminum stand with wheels)

Comment: Not very well defined: is this a radiator giving off photons, or transferring heat to convective atmospheric flow? Suppose you 'wrap' the radiator in a big aluminum foil balloon - what do you think would happen?

Comment: You are right. I didn't even describe the composition of the atmosphere in the room, not even the level of humidity and pressure! How can anybody take my question seriously like that! :-)

Comment: Just to be clear: The radiator is giving off photons, but the main process of heat transfer on a water radiator is convection, not radiation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiator_(heating)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The majority of the heating from domestic radiators is convective. The radiator heats the air immediately around it, and this air rises. The resulting convection currents spread warm air around the room and pull cold air upward from the floor to be heated by the radiators.

So the main effect of objects near radiators will be due to their effect on air flow. If the objects do not significantly reduce air flow around the radiator they will have little effect, while if they do restrict air flow they will decrease the rate at which the radiator heats the room.

Comment: Let's say the object is close enough to get hotter than the room temperature. Does that mean it's restricting the air flow?

Comment: Not necessarily. The air is obviously hotter near the radiator because it hasn't been diluted as much by the colder air in the rest of the room. So you'd expect objects nearer the radiator to be hotter. The objects heated by the radiator will themselves be heating air and therefore warming the room.